# How can I use PySpark's Window function to model exponential decay?

Tags: python, pyspark, window-functions

I am trying to apply a PySpark Window function to do "exponential decay". The formula is

```
todays_score = yesterdays_score * (weight) + todays_raw_score
```

So for example, suppose we have a dataframe that is ordered in days, and has a score of 1, every day:

```
+---+----+---------+
|day|user|raw_score|
+---+----+---------+
|  0|   a|        1|
|  1|   a|        1|
|  2|   a|        1|
|  3|   a|        1|
+---+----+---------+
```

If I were to calculate todays_score, it would look like this:

```
+---+----+---------+------------+
|day|user|raw_score|todays_score| # Here's the math:
+---+----+---------+------------+
|  0|   a|        1|         1.0| (0 * .90) + 1
|  1|   a|        1|         1.9| (1.0 * .90) + 1
|  2|   a|        1|        2.71| (1.9 * .90) + 1
|  3|   a|        1|       3.439| (2.71 * .90) + 1
+---+----+---------+------------+
```

I've tried using window functions; however based on what I've seen, they can only use the "static values" from the original dataframe, not the values we just calculated. I've even tried creating a "dummy column" to start the process; however that didn't work either.

My attempted code:

```
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame([
                                 (0, 'a', 1),
                                 (1, 'a', 1),
                                 (2, 'a', 1),
                                 (3, 'a', 1)],
    ['day', 'user', 'raw_score']
)
df.show()

# Create a "dummy column" (weighted score) so we can use it.
df2 = df.select('*', col('raw_score').alias('todays_score'))
df2.show()

w = Window.partitionBy('user') 

df2.withColumn('todays_score', 
              F.lag(F.col('todays_score'), count=1, default=0).over(w.orderBy('day'))* 0.9 + F.col('raw_score')) \
  .show()
```

The (undesired) output of this is:

```
+---+----+---------+------------+
|day|user|raw_score|todays_score|
+---+----+---------+------------+
|  0|   a|        1|         1.0|
|  1|   a|        1|         1.9|
|  2|   a|        1|         1.9|
|  3|   a|        1|         1.9|
+---+----+---------+------------+
```

which only takes the previous value * (.90), rather what was just calculated.

How can I access the values that were just calculated by the window function?

Comment: u should use a pandas grouped map udaf. is the +1 in the calculation being taken from column raw_score? or is that +1 just a static value, and what is ur spark version?

Comment: @murtihash - I want to mention 2 important things: (1) performance is a huge issue for me; I'm going to be dealing with thousands of users, with hundreds of days, and hundreds of scores... so I'm a bit hesitant to use udaf. Correct me if I'm wrong, but it's slower than the native Spark SQL functions, no? (2) Yes, the +1 is being taken from the raw score column. I have another step that calculates the scores. For the actual values, those will vary day-to-day, and not be as nice to use.

Comment: so yes u are right that it will be slower than spark in-built functions, but it will be much faster than normal udf, as it is a vectorized udf that will perform over groups of data(groupby user. map). the only other option i see is to groupby collect_list, use higher order functions to get score, and then explode the lists. besides that i dont think any other spark function can accomplish a task that is dynamic for each row. also could u please tell ur spark version, as pandas udaf is 2.3+ and higher order functions are 2.4+

Comment: @murtihash - I saw your answer below, and it goes way over head head. I was wondering if you could explain how to do it with a pandas grouped map udaf.

*Also, from my research, pandas grouped-map UDFs don't work for bounded windows. My code kept failing for that as well.

Comment: what do you mean by ' it goes way over head head', is it too slow because of the groupby and explode? or do u not understand the logic? also i have updated solution with pandas grouped map udaf. please upvote/accept answer in order to close the thread, cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For **`Spark2.4+`**, you can use higher order functions **`transform`**, **`aggregate`**, **`filter`** and **`arrays_zip`** like this. *It will work for any combination of raw_score and will be faster than pandas_udaf.* (assuming data has been ordered by day per user as shown in sample)

```
df.show() #sample dataframe
#+---+----+---------+
#|day|user|raw_score|
#+---+----+---------+
#|  0|   a|        1|
#|  1|   a|        1|
#|  2|   a|        1|
#|  3|   a|        1|
#+---+----+---------+


from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df\
  .groupBy("user").agg(F.collect_list("raw_score").alias("raw_score"),F.collect_list("day").alias("day"))\
   .withColumn("raw_score1", F.expr("""transform(raw_score,(x,i)-> struct(x as raw,i as index))"""))\
   .withColumn("todays_score", F.expr("""transform(raw_score1, x-> aggregate(filter(raw_score1,z-> z.index<=x.index)\
                                             ,cast(0 as double),(acc,y)->(acc*0.9)+y.raw))"""))\
   .withColumn("zip", F.explode(F.arrays_zip("day","raw_score","todays_score")))\
   .select("user", "zip.*")\
   .show(truncate=False)


#+----+---+---------+------------+
#|user|day|raw_score|todays_score|
#+----+---+---------+------------+
#|a   |0  |1        |1.0         |
#|a   |1  |1        |1.9         |
#|a   |2  |1        |2.71        |
#|a   |3  |1        |3.439       |
#+----+---+---------+------------+
```

**`UPDATE:`**

*Assuming data has been ordered by day as shown in sample*, you can use **`Pandas Grouped Map UDAF`** like this:

```
import pandas as pd
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.functions import pandas_udf, PandasUDFType


@pandas_udf(df.withColumn("raw_score", F.lit(1.2456)).schema, PandasUDFType.GROUPED_MAP)
def grouped_map(df):
     for i in range(1,len(df)):
          df.loc[i,'raw_score']=(df.loc[i-1,'raw_score'] * 0.9)+1   

     return df
df\
  .groupby("user").apply(grouped_map).show()

#+---+----+---------+
#|day|user|raw_score|
#+---+----+---------+
#|  0|   a|      1.0|
#|  1|   a|      1.9|
#|  2|   a|     2.71|
#|  3|   a|    3.439|
#+---+----+---------+
```